# Accept as arguments two directory paths and a string that represent an extension

Tags: shell

I can't seem to figure out this problem.

Create a script that accepts as arguments two directory path and a string that represent an extension. It should copy all files with that specific extension.

---

Example ouput:

```
$ cpByExtension d1 d0 txt
Copying ".txt" files from directory d1 to directory d0
0 files copied
$ cpByExtension d2 d0 txt
Copying ".txt" files from directory d2 to directory d0
5 files copied
$
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  What have you tried?  What does the outline of your attempted solution look like?  Where are you having problems with that attempt?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You will first want to handle the input. You know your are taking `two paths` and `an extension`, so your arguments are `$1`, `$2` and `$3` as:

```
#!/bin/sh

## validate input
if [ -z "$1" -o -z "$2" -o -z "$3" ]; then
    printf "error: insufficient input. Usage: %s <dir1> <dir2> <ext>\n\n" "$0"
fi
```

Once you know you have your input, then you may consider testing each directory to make sure they exist:

```
## validate dirs
if [ ! -d "$1" -o ! -d "$2" ]; then
    printf "error: invalid directory. Usage: %s <dir1> <dir2> <ext>\n\n" "$0"
fi
```

Knowing the directories exist (or you can just test the first and create the second), you can now copy matching files:

```
cp "$1"/*."$3" "$2"
```

Will copy all files from dir1 (`$1`) to dir2 (`$2`) that match the `*.ext` filespec.

You can, of course, assign the input arguments to variables if you wish. Example:

```
dir1="$1"
dir2="$2"
ext="$3"
```

This is more readable and can make the logic easier to understand. Your file copy would then become:

```
cp "$dir1"/*."$ext" "$dir2"
```

Comment: thank you, it helped a lot, I had problem with the extension. Thumps up!